# RegEx Javascript - Only 0-2 spaces or hyphens in whole string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, limit, spaces

I have the following simple regex:
`/^[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+$/`

i would like to make it possible to have strings like "Blabla Bla bshfkhsf".
But the whole string should not have more then 2 spaces or hyphens.

I know, that i can limit spaces with "\s{0,2}", but how do i place such limit
in the regex, so that strings like above are possible and the limit applies to the whole string, not to a "single" character?

EDIT:
May this be ok:

```
^[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+((\s)|(-))?[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+((\s)|(-))?[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+$
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: More than 2 spaces overall, or in consequence? For example, is `'a  a  a'` fine?

Comment: Optionally repeat the whole part 0 - 2 times and use a character class `[\s-]` to match either a hyphen or a whitespace char `^[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+){0,2}$` https://regex101.com/r/NPOx7h/1

Comment: Split the to be tested string at any single whitespace and test the length of the resulting array. For examplke `sampleText.split(/\s/).length <= 3` was the test condition of a string that matches the requirements of your Q.

Comment: @raina77ow: only one space between characters(words).
Thefourthbird: Is the {0,2} at the end not for the characters too?
PeterSeliger: Yes, i know that i just can count the spaces, but it's not so elegant.
EDIT: Ok Thefourthbird, i understand...

Comment: Why's `-` in your pattern? Should `-` be covered too?

Comment: Yes, the `-` too

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to match spaces only, you can match the first part, then use the quantifier `{0,2}` to repeat the whole part again preceded by a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[\s-]` to match either a whitespace char or a hyphen.

If it should be a whitespace char only, you could use a mere `\s` (which could also match a newline)

**Note** that in your pattern, the whole alternation `((\s)|(-))?` is optional so the minimum length of a single match would be 3 characters in that case. [See this example](https://regex101.com/r/PaTit9/1).

You could update the pattern to

```
^[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+){0,2}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[\s-]` Match either a whitspace char or `-`
  - `[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
- `){0,2}` Close the group and repeat it 0-2 times
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AqYMoM/1)

Comment: What's `[\s-]` supposed to mean?

Comment: @raina77ow It is a character class that matches one of the listed characters.

Comment: Ah yes, the code given by the OP indeed has that hyphen. It contradicts the OP's post (- is not whitespace), but I see your point here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already understood, but thanks for the explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeating the whole character class, you can just use [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to combine the conditions:

```
/^(?=[^\s-]*([\s-][^\s-]*){0,2}$)[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df\s-]+$/
```

[**Regex 101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/4BfqZf/1). It's essentially two regexes in one:

```
(?=[^\s-]*([\s-][^\s-]*){0,2}$)
```

This part checks whether or not the whole string satisfies 'not more than 2 whitespace or - characters' rule.

```
[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df\s-]+$
```

This part checks whether or not the whole string satisfies 'only letters, whitespace and hyphens' rule. The point is, whole pattern matches only if both checks pass.

Comment: Hmm. That sounds good, but i don't understand the first part.

Comment: What exactly is unclear? Do you know how lookahead works?

Comment: No, i hear the first time about lookahead. Must read about it know...

Comment: That's ok, live and learn. :) Using lookaheads the way described lets us combine several conditions which would be inconvenient to merge in a pattern otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation. Seems like it is the "smartest" way even if it looks more like hieroglyphs then the other answer ;)

Comment: can you tell me, why i can write more then one dot at the following regex `(?=[^\s-]*([\s-][^\s-]*){0,2}\.?$)`. I don't understand that. It should be only 0 or 1 dot because the question marker or am i wrong?

Comment: I'm not really sure I got your idea here. What are you trying to check with that pattern: that the line might end with a dot, but that's not necessary?

Comment: I just try different things like that: `^(?=[^\s-]+([\s-][^\s-]+){0,2}\.?\s\d+\s?[a-gA-G]?$)[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df\s\-\.\d]+$`. But why i can write more than 1 dot?

Comment: Sorry, you're losing me here. It's hard to answer your question without understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: The test is about a street and number like "Donald Str. 47" or "Donald Street 47", so 0 or 1 dot is possible

Comment: So you're writing a regex for validating the address lines? Why didn't you tell that in the first place? There's a lot more rules you need to bear in mind, more than just 'not more than 2 whitespaces' - that very dot might appear at the beginning of the line if it's an abbreviation, for example.

Comment: No, the validation of address is just a test, a "training" to understand things better

Comment: Please try to avoid "Inception"-type questions here at SO, when there's a new layer uncovered each time one answers the previous one. If you want to understand something, place that something in your head - and move on, asking future questions if necessary. SO questions are not replacement for proper training on any topic - regular expressions in particular.

Comment: Ah ok. I think i understand now. The "other" dots are interpreted as a part of "[^\s-]+", right? EDIT: Ok, thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Parapharasing your requirement, you need to match a string that cannot have three or more spaces.

Use

```
/^(?!(?:\S*\s){3})[a-zA-Z\s\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+$/
  ^++++++++++++++^       ^^
```

So,

1. `\s` is added to the expression so that it could match whitespace
2. `(?!(?:\S*\s){3})` ensures no three or more whitespace occurs in the string (there can be any non-whitespace characters in between thanks to `\S*`).

**More things to consider**

To disallow spaces at the start and end add more lookaheads

```
/^(?!\s)(?!.*\s$)(?!(?:\S*\s){3})[a-zA-Z\s\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+$/
  ^+++++++++++++^
```

To also disallow consecutive spaces

```
/^(?!\s)(?!.*\s$)(?!.*\s{2})(?!(?:\S*\s){3})[a-zA-Z\s\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+$/
                 ^+++++++++^
```